# Blazor Server Dll loading progress

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, startup

I have a blazor project. At application startup it loads a lot of Dll files. During this time window, nothing is shown on the browser. The page is blank with loading progress circle running on Chrome. When all dll and javascript scripts are loaded, then the application route starts and someting appears on the browser screen.

How is it possible to intercept the startup loading progress and to show the loading progress in the Browser on a Blazor Server application? I found many articles that explain this matter but only for Blazor Webassembly projects, while none for Blazor Server projects.

Thanks in advance
Paolo

---

### Edit

Starting from a Blazor Server Project, how is it possible to show in the Browser a progress bar that prints the Dll's loading progress?

Comment: Ideally you should post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What does your landing page look like?  Are you doing a lot of slow data acquisition?  Most of the doll's will already be loaded as part of the web server startup.

Comment: No thanks, what i need is to understand how to intercept and display the first application loading process